BigQuery external table limitations
I have e-commerce product details stored in CSV format in the GCS bucket. Each file contains the attributes of a single product. The number of such files is approximately 4 billion.
I am planning to use a BigQuery external table to query the data.
It worked when I tested with 10 million such files. My question is, will it work when the number of files is as high as 4 billion? Even if it takes time (15-30 mins), it is fine.
What are the other recommended options to query the data if we don't use the BigQuery external table? 

We use GCP workflows to load the text files into a BQ table. Workflows can be triggered by the creation of a file in a bucket, the filename is then passed to the import method and the file can be loaded:
https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorials/load-data-from-cloud-storage-to-bigquery-using-workflows

Thank you for the reply. When I read the document, it looks like it explains how to use workflows to populate data in native BigQuery tables from GCS buckets.
I want to continue with external BigQuery tables. My concern is, will BigQuery external tables work when I am pointing to a GCS bucket that has 4 billion files, each with a size of 100KB?

yeah, you'll have to try it and see how it goes... haha... 4billion files does seem like a lot.

can you let me know how it goes? I'd be very interested to know if it has performance or other issues (like one file breaks the whole table errors).
